# Strange loss curve while training LSTM with Keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I'm trying to train an LSTM for some a binary classification problem. When I plot `loss` curve after the training, there are strange picks in it. Here are some examples:

[image]

[image]

Here is the basic code

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(recurrent.LSTM(128, input_shape = (columnCount,1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(recurrent.LSTM(128, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
             loss='binary_crossentropy', 
             metrics=['accuracy'])

new_train = X_train[..., newaxis]

history = model.fit(new_train, y_train, nb_epoch=500, batch_size=100, 
                    callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.0001, patience=2, verbose=0, mode='auto'), 
                                 ModelCheckpoint(filepath="model.h5", verbose=0, save_best_only=True)],
                    validation_split=0.1)

# list all data in history
print(history.history.keys())
# summarize history for loss
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

I don't understand why do that picks occur? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you shuffle your training data?

Answer (score 7):

There are many possibilities why something like this occurs:

1. **Your parameters trajectory changed its basin of attraction** - this means that your system left a stable trajectory and switched to another one. This was probably due to randomization like e.g. batch sampling or dropout.
2. **LSTM instability**- **LSTM**s are believed to be extremely unstable in terms of training. It was also reported that very often it's really time consuming for them to stabilize.

Due to the latest research (e.g. from [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.10239.pdf)) I would recommend you decreasing the batch size and leaving it for more epochs. I would also try to check if e.g. topology of a network is not to complexed (or plain) in terms of amount of patterns it need to learn. I would also try switch to either `GRU` or `SimpleRNN`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try them and let you know about results.

Comment: great tips, @nabroyan yes almost always this can be attributed to too large batches. I'd also try different optimizers, rmsprop and adadelta with a tuned learning rate can sometimes be a good alternative. If nothing helps drop straight down to SGD with fairly small learning rate.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but I've seen this happen before when re-starting training from a checkpoint. If the spike corresponded to a break in training, you may be inadvertently resetting some of the weights.